# WPF Save Changes in DataGrid to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, data-transfer

My application requires that changes made in the WPF `DataGrid` control are saved back to the `DataTable`.  I have managed to save data from the `DataGrid` to `DataTable`, however, the data saved from the `DataGrid` does not show the changes I have made, it just shows the data that was already there when the `DataGrid` was first populated.

I have got this far:

```
public void UpdateQueueData(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
     {
         DataGridRow dgRow = e.Row;
         DataRowView rowView = dgRow.Item as DataRowView;
         DataRow drItem = rowView.Row;
         Queue.Rows.RemoveAt(e.Row.GetIndex());
         Queue.ImportRow(drItem);
         WriteXML();
     }
 }
```

This works but it does not save the changes, it just saves the `DataRow` as it was before it was changed in the `DataGrid`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer!. I have to Get the `DataRow` that was being changed:

```
private void dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ((DataView)dataGridQueue.ItemsSource).ToTable();
    // Set the value of my datatable to the the changed version before 
    // writing it so a file.
    dt.WriteXMLScema(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx) after you make your changes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the changes made in the datagrid were not showing up in the DataRow: drItem when the event was being trigged.